How to add pagination/counter in the API gateway to control the output from Lambda Python
I am having a lambda function which is exposed as a Rest API-endpoint  through API Gateway. The lambda function is reading multiple files from S3 through python and sending the response through APIGW based on some condition in the python code. In output response I am appending all the responses in a single common JSON.
Now As size of the combined JSON eventually can be very big which may cause problem in performance ,I want to have some pagination option like offset/cursor at the API gateway so that through the exposed rest API anyone can control the lambda function on what number of files in  S3 bucket they want to traverse in one call and next time the API can resume from the very next file  where the first API ends.
Please advice me the efficient way to achieve this expectation.

There are many ways to accomplish this.  One common pattern is to have a limit on the number of files processed, and if it's hit return the key of the final object processed from the lambda as some sort of "NextToken" and use that in further calls as an input to ListObject's StartAfter value.

Start by taking a cue from how AWS itself does it: if I call s3:ListObjects, I get everything matching the provided prefix.  If I only want 100 objects at a time, then I add a "MaxResults" parameter set to 100; that will return the first the first 100 results and a "NextToken" value that will allow me to obtain additional results.  In your case, you can add these two parameters to your Function (make them optional, just like AWS does) to allow your callers to split up responses however they like.
The hard part is designing your pagination tokens.  Key design considerations include:

Imagine the scenario where a query is made that matches objects a, b, c, and d.  The caller requested that responses be returned in batches of 2, so you return (a, b, token) with the expectation that the token can be used to return (c, d).  Then before the token gets used, someone deletes c.  What do you do now?  Do you only return (d), somehow disallow the deletion operation, or keep a reference to c such that it's still accessible to a call using the token but not to new calls?
As above, but imagine that someone adds a new object e that matches the query.
Do pagination tokens expire?  If so, how long are they valid and how do you detect an expired token?  This can be more or less important depending on how you answer the above questions.
What happens if you need to change your token format?  Can you just kill off any pagination operations in progress or do you need to allow them to continue to operate using the old format?  The safe way to solve this is to include a version identifier in each token and continue to support old token formats until you can safely assume that all pagination operations using old tokens have completed or timed out.
How much do you trust your users?  If they're not fully trusted, then you want to prevent them from trying to craft pagination tokens that might make your application behave in ways that you didn't intend, trying to use stolen pagination tokens issued to other users, etc.  The usual way to accomplish this is to digitally sign tokens that you issue (including the ID of the principal to whom it was assigned, its format version, and its expiration time), then verify the signature before using a token.
Does your token expose application internals that you don't want your users to know?  If so, you should encrypt your tokens (before signing them).

Once you've solved all of that, you can worry about the basics like "How can I identify the set of objects that have been returned already or that haven't yet been returned?".  I'm not exactly sure what you're doing here but maybe you can just forward a token generated by S3.  More generally, if you're making queries to something else that just returns lists in deterministic order (and you've somehow solved the object-insertion and object-deletion problems), then your token can just be an index into the list.  If you're limiting your response size based on bytes rather than objects, then maybe you need to include a byte offset as well.  Maybe you need to sort your list of objects into a well-defined and consistent order, and include in your tokens both an index into that list and the unique ID of the next object in the list (in order to detect scenarios where the list has changed due to addition or removal).
